# Common JavaScript Closure issue on jQuery elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am working at building a widget that calls a particular plugin on each jQuery DOM element inside an array.

MyApp.forms is an array of Objects. Each Object has a jQuery wrapped DOM element.

I am doing the following:

```
$(MyApp.forms).each(function(i){
    var individualForm = this;
    /*
    individualForm is an Object {
        prop: 'value,
        $el: somejQueryElement,
        ...
    }
    */
    individualForm.$el.thePlugin({
        // options
    })
    .on('pluginEvent', function() {
        individualForm; // refers to the last object in MyApp.forms
        this; // refers to the last 
        $(this); // same problem
    }).on('pluginEvent2', function() {
        // same problem as above here.
    });
});
```

The events `pluginEvent` and `pluginEvent2` get attached to all `individualForm`'s `$el`. But when they fire, I always get the last element.
I feel this is a common JavaScript Closure problem.

I tried using a `for` loop and creating an `IIFE` inside but it doesn't work, as the function executes when the event fires. And though both events fire on all elements, I only get the handler attached to last element executed.

**Update**:

Found The fix. But don't know why and how it worked.
Every `individualForm.$el` element is an `input` element with `class="some-class"`.

Somewhere else in the code, another developer is doing `$('.some-class').bind(...` with an older version of jQuery. And then again with a newer version of jQuery (using `noConflict` `$`). There are 2 `jQuery`'s on the page. The fix was to delete the first `.bind`.

Comment: I made a simple demo with your structure here http://jsfiddle.net/v9hWB/ and it seems to work fine

Comment: @koala_dev, yes :(. I have updated the question, if that helps. I also using the plugin before binding the events.

Comment: Something else must be wrong. Are you sure that `individualForm` is local to the `each` callback? Are you accidentally setting `individualForm.$el` for each object to the same element? The code you posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Just to be clear: If the code is as you posted it, then this is not the typical "function-definition-in-a-loop" problem, because you are not explicitly using a `for` loop (or any other loop).

Comment: @FelixKling, yes. I tried to use `for` loop as a solution. Didn't work.  
Also, I am attaching events in a for loop.

Comment: *"Also, I am attaching events in a for loop."* But not in the code you posted, so that doesn't explain the behavior you see. Given the code in the question, the only reason why it would exhibit this problem is that you are messing with each object's `$el` property. But without more information, we cannot really help you.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am attaching the event in an `each` loop, which is ultimately a for loop, right? But it is a known fact that jQ's `each` does not mess with the `this`. I am also trying to get some more info for you.

Comment: @Om: Right, jQuery surely does a `for` loop or so in the background, but the point is that there are no variables shared between each iteration if you use `.each`. The callback is executed for each iteration and all the variables are local to it. The "closure-loop" problem only arises if multiple functions access the same variables (usually the loop variable).

Comment: How about you include the code where you create the forms array, that may help us pinpoint the issue

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the following:

```
$(MyApp.forms).each(function(i){
    var form = this;
    (function(individualForm) {
        individualForm.$el.on('something', function() {
            individualForm; // refers to the last object in MyApp.forms
            this; // refers to the last 
            $(this); // same problem
        }).on('somethingElse', function() {
            // same problem as above here.
        });
    })(form);
});
```

You should wrap individualForm in a closure. Otherwise the scope is changed and it points to the last element of the array.

Comment: That's completely unnecessary. You only need to do this if you are creating functions inside a loop (`for`, `while`, ...), which you are not doing here

Comment: This symptom *"But when they fire, I always get the last element."* is exactly cause by such behaviour and the solution is above. As far as I can see in the code of jQuery the .each implementation involves for loop. However, Om Shankar can you please try the proposed solution in your code.

Comment: The usual problem with closure in a loop is that the loop variables (e.g. `i`) is "shared" by all functions that are created in the loop. That's not the case here though. The `.each` callback is executed for each element, i.e. in each invocation, you create a *local* variable `form`. This variable is not shared between multiple calls of the `.each` callback. Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/fbyvW/. You are right, the problem *sounds* like the typical "closure-loop" problem, but there are not closures created in a loop in the code, hence it cannot be it.

Comment: @FelixKling: now I agree with you. Then it looks like the *$el* in *individualForm.$el* is a pointer to same object.

Comment: That's what I think as well. But without more code/information, we cannot really pinpoint the problem (we can only say what it is not ;)).